# What is a good workflow for hiring freelancers?

Tags: software-development

Should I allow the freelancer to clone my entire repository to work on my code?
Is this safe?  I don't feel like giving a complete stranger access to my entire code base.

Basically, how do I use the tool **Git** in project management to facilitate development with out having my entire web app completely open?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a project management question. Can you refocus the question on the practical project management issues as described in [ask]?

Comment: You don't want to hire people you cannot trust. If you don;t feel comfortable with them accessing your code, how can you trust them to write more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the freelancer to work on your codebase, you either make him sign a NDA, or provide access to the repositories.

Alternatively, you can specify and API that a freelancer should implement, and you'll use it through the API.

Nevertheless, the freelancer (or anybody) can do a better work if he can see the whole picture.

Comment: How can I get the NDA signed over the web?

Comment: @cadegalt: Papers can be signed, scanned and then emailed back.